# BeautifulSoup pagination using href

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pagination

I am trying to scrape all thee events from https://www.onthisday.com/events/february/5 I am getting all the events from first page.How can I get other events from the second page and merge into one list?

Right now I tried to catch the next page link and parse it but it didn't work still getting the results from first page.

Here is my code:

```
from typing import List
import requests as _requests
import bs4 as _bs4

def _generate_url(month: str, day: int) -> str:
    url = f'https://www.onthisday.com/events/{month}/{day}'
    return url

def _get_page(url: str) -> _bs4.BeautifulSoup:
    _page = _requests.get(url)
    soup = _bs4.BeautifulSoup(_page.content, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def events_of_the_day(month: str, day: int) -> List[str]:
    """
    Return the events of a given day
    """
    
    url = _generate_url(month, day)
    page = _get_page(url)
    next_link = page.select_one("a.pag__next")
    raw_events = [event.text for event in page.select("li.event")]
    if next_link:
        next_url = 'https://www.onthisday.com/events'+next_link['href']
        page_next = _get_page(next_url)
        for eve in page_next.select("li.event"):
            print(eve.text)
    
    #print(raw_events)
    

events_of_the_day("february", 5)
```

**Note:**

Some pages contains the next page and some don't so I am looking to handle both the situations.

Answer (score 0):

Upon inspecting the page, the next button is nothing but a link.

```html
<a href="/events/february/5?p=2" class="pag__next" rel="next">
  <span>Next</span>
</a>
```

Note the link `/events/february/5?p=2`. All you need to do is iterate over a range and make the request call. Whenever you hit 404, you exit the loop. I'll leave the looping to you.

EDIT

```py
i = 1
while True:
  res = request.get(f"https://www.onthisday.com/events/february/5?p={i}")
  if is_visited(res.content):
    # TODO write a function to check if you have visited these contents
    break
  ...
  # TODO wirte a function to updated the visited list or something similar
  visited(res.content)

  i+=1 # incrementing i
```

Comment: I'd like to see some example code for clarification if you don't mind.

Comment: @dougj there you go

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching and debugging I finally came up with the solution to dynamically go through all the pagination if there is or if there is none all I have to do is create `while loop` and check for the `next_link` that is it.

Code:

```
while True:
        page = _get_page(url)
        for event in page.select('li.event'):
            events.append(event.text)
        next_link = page.select_one('a.pag__next')
        if not next_link:
            break
        url = 'https://www.onthisday.com'+next_link['href']
```